# R Syntax Auto-completion for Stat ET / Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, r, code-completion

I just moved to Eclipse/StatET to code in R. My understanding is that syntax completions appears with Ctrl + Space and you should get some basic functions/argurments information. But

I get almost nothing:

Simple functions as 'plot' are not even listed.
Actually no function starting with the letter p is listed... It just displays a minimum of syntax for loops for instance.

Is it normal ? Is there a way to link it to the R online syntax documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things. You need to use the RMI/RJ console (specified in the Launch type of you run configuration), code completion does not work on the RTerm console.

On the "R Console" tab (still in your run configuration) you need to "enable Object DB"

When that is done, launch R and load the packages you need. You should see the "Object browser" view being populated.

At that point I bet code completion will work!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dr G. I tried to enable the RJ console but I have the folowing error message: 
"[JRE]: Selected R and Java environments are not compatible: R = 64-bits, JRE = 32-bits"  which I keep having even after re-installing JRE 64bits (I am running Windows 7 pro 64). 

"enable Object DB" is enabled.

Any clue regarding the JRE error message ?

Comment: Running $> system("java -version")  returns 
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to fix it, I was using Eclipse 32bits that I got from the pythonxy installer. Replacing it by the latest Eclispe 64bits fixed the wrong JRE error.

Thanks for your help Dr G.